# Batch file: write a command in fresh made cmd with other title

Tags: windows, batch-file, tomcat, cmd

I have a batch file that runs my tomcat server:

.cmd-file

```
REM This is the startup
start cmd.exe /k title killthis 
call catalina run
```

Now if i run this, tomcat will start inside my batch file. But what i want to do is to run my catalina(tomcat) in the cmd window with title "killthis". I searched the whole internet but couldn't find it, please can anyone help? I've been thinking about this for a week or so.

Operating System: 
-Windows 7 Professional

Kind Regards

Comment: you mean something like `START "killthis" cmd.exe /k catalina run`

Comment: Yup, @GerhardBarnard. That's exactly what i need, thanks!

Comment: ok, posting an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running `start /?` you will see all the relevant help and switches, but you want:

```
START "killthis" cmd.exe /k catalina run
```